# After putting a Windows computer to sleep, is there a way to enable a "grace period" where touching the mouse or keyboard will NOT wake it up?

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard, mouse, sleep

Here's an extremely annoying thing which happens to me regularly:

1. Go to Start menu -> choose "Sleep" to put computer in stand-by mode.
2. Computer begins to go to sleep.
3. As I stand up from my chair, my desk might vibrate and my mouse might move slightly, or I might accidentally hit a single key on the keyboard as the computer prepares to sleep.
4. Computer turns off and then immediately turns back on again because of the above.

It's extremely annoying and I feel like there should be a grace period of at least a few seconds where the computer is *not* awoken by input.

I know I could stop the keyboard/mouse from waking the computer via Power Options but that's more of an inconvenient workaround than a cure.

Comment: Moving your mouse won't wake up your PC, but clicking it does. However, waking up settings are brand-specific, e.g. some Toshiba laptop only wake up when pressing the power button; Asus laptops when pressing any key; but moving the mouse has no effect on any brand, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the Start menu command, you could use a timer such as 
http://www.pc-sleep.com/

This way, you tell the computer to sleep in 2 minutes time (for example), and walk away. It goes to sleep after you've left the desk.